# How to index text that spans several pages?

Tags: imakeidx

I'm sure this is built into the `index` command or a similar command but my google searches are coming up empty. I want to index text that spans several pages. So, something like the MWE below. (Though this this is technically an MnotWE)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index[begin=darwin]{Darwin}Species compete for survival.
Blah blah for several pages.\index[end=darwin]{}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried "To specify a page range, put an `\index{...|(}` command at the beginning of the range and an `\index{...|)}` command at the end of the range."? (`texdoc makeindex`)

Comment: @Cicada Thanks! That's what I was looking for.